# failed to convert string to int in csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new in pandas and having a problem
Failed to convert String to float while reading csv file using pandas,i have used so far

```
pd.read_csv('Book2.csv',delimiter=',', index_col=0, skiprows=1,converters={'Open Price (Rs.)':float})
```

and tried dtype also

both gives an error 
I am sharing the csv file link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_RSbeIckLLeRlByUlhxUGJ2dWc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
modelFeatures = [contains all the columns' names you use]
df = df[modelFeatures].astype(float)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check line 1873 in the CSV file - it has a header line (column labels).